# Pop up is not closed on clicking of User control button In WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

Opening pop up on click of icon in user control

```
    <Popup x:Name="pp1" Placement="Center" AllowsTransparency="False" PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=grdCT}" IsOpen="{Binding ElementName=btnAdd, Path=IsChecked, Mode=TwoWay}"  Closed="pp1_Closed" StaysOpen="false" PopupAnimation="Slide" >
                <local:FDataControl x:Name="controlFDataControl" Background="White" BorderThickness="2" Width="388"/>
   </Popup>
```

In when pop up opens it have one user control which have button to close pop up i want to close this pop up by clicking on close button of that popuped User control.
i tried with staysopen=false and Isopen=true
Please suggest that will ne needfull

Comment: Please include `btnAdd`, since you try to bind its `IsChecked`

Answer (score 0):

you can write in code behind of user control:

```
void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs){
  Popup popup = this.FindVisualParent<Popup>();
  if(popup == null) return;
  popup.IsOpen = false;
}
```

Regards

Steffen